# Having trouble with using functions in for loop

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, definition

```
X=[1,2,1,0,1]
def f(x):
     return {1:'car',2:'bike',0:'bus'}.get(x,'default')

for i in X:
    print(i)
    f(i)
output: 1 2 1 0 1
```

The problem with the above code is, its not executing the function f(x)

Comment: It is. What makes you think it's not?

Comment: `f()` result is unused and is not printing anything, how would you know it's not called ?

Comment: Mad Physicist, if it is executing the f(x), then it should return car, bike, car,bus,car.

Comment: gogaz, can you help me to get the output in needed as mentioned in above comment ?

Comment: @Durairajs What they are saying is you are calling your function `f(x)` but not doing anything with the result. The reason your just get `1 2 1 0 1` is that is all that you are calling the `print` method on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this? It proves that it's executing normally

```
X=[1,2,1,0,1]
def f(x):
     return {1:'car',2:'bike',0:'bus'}.get(x,'default')

for i in X:
    print(i)
    print(f(i))
```